# Hadoop mapreduce.job.reduces in Generic Option Syntax?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to set the number of reducers to use via command line. It seems like I am using wrong syntax. I am using hadoop 2.5 (yarn) MR2.

```
hadoop jar mrjobs-0.1.jar com.example.Weather -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 datasets/inputs output
```

This commands is not working when I added -D option else its working fine.

Any help appreciated !

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax looks proper, I have tested against 2.5 YARN MR2 with the following it's working:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=5 input output
```

Most probably the problem could be your Driver class hasn't implemented [ToolRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) which works in coordination with GenericOptionsParser to parse generic command line arguments.

Here is an example of how to implement ToolRunner in your MapReduce Driver class:

```java
// imports ignored

public class ExampleDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ExampleDriver <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

        job.setJobName("example driver");
        job.setJarByClass(ExampleDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(YourMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(YourReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        int ret = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ExampleDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```